# NodeJS - Use variable for function option

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following:

```
    offers.loadPartnerInventory({
        partnerSteamId: steam_id,
        appId: 730,
        contextId: 2
      }, function(err, items) {
        // picking first tradable item
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          if (items[i].tradable) {
            if (items[i].id == item.asset_id ) {
                logger.info('match found');
                checkedItem = items[i];
                break;
            }
          }
        }
     });
```

`steam_id = '435345'`

If I hardcode the string I get the correct results however using the variable I get the following:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: The only functions you call here are `logger.info` and `offers.loadPartnerInventory` and I don't think that `logger` is influenced by `steam_id`. So the error happens at another place and is mentioned by nodejs with the error message. Beside that you should always check if the `err` of your callback is set or not.

Comment: There's not even close to enough information included in this question to know what question is really being asked and/or help solve a specific problem.  Please start over and show a specific snippet of code that gives you a specific error and include the exact error message and show the exact line where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var steam_id = '435345';
offers.loadPartnerInventory({
        partnerSteamId: steam_id,
        appId: 730,
        contextId: 2
      }, function(err, items) {
        // picking first tradable item
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          if (items[i].tradable) {
            if (items[i].id == item.asset_id ) {
                logger.info('match found');
                checkedItem = items[i];
                break;
            }
          }
        }
     });
```

Is `steam_id` defined before you use it in code, or after you attempt to use it?